# List of struct and pointers

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, structure

I have a function which gets a pointer pointer to a person list, and two ints which contain the position of two persons in that list.

```
int relation(Person **p_list, int p1, int p2)
{

printf("At Übergabe: %s\n", (*p_list + p1)->name_); //Prints name person1
printf("At Übergabe: %s\n", (*p_list + p2)->name_); //Prints name person2

int relative;
Person **Person1;
Person **Person2;

Person1 = (p_list + p1);
Person2 = (p_list + p2);

printf("Post Übergabe: %s\n", (*Person1)->name_); //Prints name person2
printf("Post Übergabe: %s\n", (*Person2)->name_); //memory error

return PLZ_WORK;
}
```

And i dont get it... i would get if both would produce a memory error... but i dont get why the first person is now the second one, and the second violates my memory...

Edit:

```
typedef struct _Person_
{
char name_[MAX_NAME];
char sex_;
}Person;
```

Comment: So you are off by one somewhere.

Comment: How is `Person` defined?

Comment: Note that in the first pair of `printf()` calls, you used `(*p_list + p1)`.  In `Person1 = (p_list +  p1);` (with its unnecessary parentheses), you don't have the `*`, which changes the meaning — dramatically. If `p1` is 0, it might work; if it is larger, it most likely won't.

Comment: Yeah I guess its an off by one error, but i cant find it... I mean it worked for putting out the names in the first go, so i only want a pointer to the entire struct instead of just the name...

Comment: Invoking undefined behavior does not guarantee a crash.

Comment: And if i set Person1 = (*p_list + p1); it gives me a warning and if i run it, I get that memory violation instantly...

Comment: because `Person1` is a `Person**` (as is `p_list + p1`) whereas `*p_list + p1` is a `Person*`. Ignoring the warning leads to undefined behavior because the types are different. `Person1` should be a `Person*` instead.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks!

If I was stupid enough and required the rest of the function that Person1 and Person to are Person** how would i make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written Person1 and Person2 point indiscriminately into memory. Chances are you are getting lucky with the values of p1 and the pointer ends up pointing ( by dumb chance the way the memory lays ) to the other name. The other value of p2 pushes the value of the pointer into an area of memory which you aren't allowed to access.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense... But how to fix it? The suggestion of replacing Person1 = (p_list + p1); with Person1 = (*p_list + p1); doenst work because the compiler tells me those are incompatible pointer types

Comment: Indeed they are incompatible. Declare Person1, Person2 as Person* ( not **). Then *p_list is a pointer to a Person and *p_list + p1 points to (hopefully) a valid Person.

Comment: You'll need to edit (*Person1)->name_  to just Person1->name_ as well.

Comment: yeah that part seems to work now, thanks. Since all the sub functions require a Person** I should just write example `silbings(&Person1, &Person2)` ?

Comment: Sorry, that is more of a strategy question.

Comment: Well it works now, thanks. I still have to fix a few Nullpointer exceptions, but thats managable